# Refresh content automatically if the database changes

Tags: php, mysql, database

how can I automatically add the value of a database row (PHP), to the page, without refreshing the page itself, when the mysql database table changes?

So, it is a bit like this: [Automatically refresh browser in response to file system changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309599/automatically-refresh-browser-in-response-to-file-system-changes) , **but** instead of refreshing the browser with the file system changes, update the content, without refreshing anything, when the databse changes.

Thanks. I have tried to make this as clear as possible.

Comment: Do you mean for exmaple, something like facebook comments. When new comments inserted to the database, you will refresh the display on the client-side ?

Comment: @LaithShadeed Yes, but keep what you are already typing.

Comment: You could use javascript's setInterval() and $.ajax to poll a PHP script that returns updated rows back to the page.

Comment: @mhoofman So you suggest that I see a setInterval, say, every 500 milliseconds, and update at that time, so you don't check if the database changes. That sounds like an easy workaround :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Please note this is outdated answer. Recent ways of doing that is: websockets, server-send events. Nice example of that is Firebase. You can find simple code example in: https://github.com/laithshadeed/wsk-feedback. In this example you will see that updating firebase will send event to the browser via websocket, then the UI will update.

This is called Comet/Reverse Ajax/HTTP server push http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming). They are many techniques for doing this as well as many existing frameworks to do it for you.

There are many answers in SO about Comet https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comet

Simple implementation would be javascript setTimeout and setInterval to check server status, with trigger/stored procedure on mysql.

For depth dive into Comet. There are two cool books about this:

[Comet and Reverse Ajax 2008 By Dave Crane](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599985)

[image: Comet and Reverse Ajax Cover Image]

[Chapter 4 (River of Content) -  Building the Realtime User Experience 2010 By Ted Roden](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806159)

[image: Building the Realtime User Experience Cover image]

> **Update**: You may look to the newer techniques in HTML5 like [Websockets and Server-sent](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) Events, although IE does not support them well, at the moment Server-sent events is [not supported in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource) and Web Sockets only [supported in IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)

Comment: I think I'm going for setTimeout and setInterval. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a truly simple task, but it's not that bad.  You need a few things working in concert:

- A javascript routine on your page that checks with the server at specifiedintervals
- A page on your server that reports changes when polled
- A callback function on your page that inserts new elements (or updates/deletes existing elements) when changed data is reported by the server.

How you determine which data has been changed is something you will have to think about. The easiest way is probably to have a "modified" field maintained for each record.  This way when your javascript polls the server it can include a "last time I checked" timestamp and the server only has to return changes that are more recent.

It's not quite so hard as it may at first appear.  Take advantage of prebuilt libraries like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and you can do things like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/checkforupdates.php?last=' + (new Date().getTime()),
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    // do something here to add/update/remove elements on your page
    // using the information returned in the data argument.
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds hard, is there any code that I can use to do this, e.g any examples. As I can't seem to find any

Answer (score -4):

Manipulate the DOM with JavaScript.