# Updating a page when data changes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

It has been a long time since I have worked with PhP or Javascript and I want to build a website that runs on a server with MYSql that can update the page when the data in the MYSQl table changes.

I am not sure how to do this, if anyone has any ideas I'd love a boost.

Comment: Why is this css tagged?

Comment: if your webpage already showing your Table data then after update it will update itself simple i cannot see reason to tags css jaavascript tags

Comment: Serious question.  I forgot to how to do this ita been so long and google isnt helping me.  Css because it has to add a div that is defined in css

Comment: How would you update itself witthout javascript?  I dont want the page to refresh i want it to just remove and add divs smoothly

Comment: A Database change won't trigger a page refresh for itself. You would have to periodically check for the table data from the page script...

Answer (score 0):

assuming this data is being gathered using an SQL SELECT statement,
move your statement and the way in which it displays the results into a different file.
then you can load the results from the query into a div using jquery .load

```
$("#someDiv").load("somefile.php");
```

If the data is not being updated from the page in which you want it auto refreshed, use setInterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){
        $("#someDiv").load("somefile.php");
    }), 2000);    

});
```

with 2000 meaning it will run every 2 seconds.

If you are updating the data and want the updated results shown without the need for a page refresh, use ajax and in its 'success' function call:

```
$("#someDiv").load("somefile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a webpage to be notified of a change in the server. More specifically, you want the data in your page to be refreshed when the data in your database changes.

You have at least two options:

- You write some javascript so that you browser periodically asks (**polls**) the server for changes via ajax (as another user has already explained). You could even consider long polling.

or...

- You make use of **websockets**, which will allow your server to **push** the data to the client whenever the server wants.

You may want to take a look at the many posts in SO which discuss this matter.

[Refresh content automatically if the database changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100594/refresh-content-automatically-if-the-database-changes)

[Automatically refresh browser in response to file system changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309599/automatically-refresh-browser-in-response-to-file-system-changes)

[How can I refresh a page when a database is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629642/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-when-a-database-is-updated)