# Call Ajax only when new row inserted in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building a chat system. I am sending ajax request after **every 2 second** to get new messages. Now the problem is that after every 2 second ajax call I reload **all messages** again from message Table instead of fetching just new message..

What I want is that when page is load first time then **all messages would load** and then after that just load the new message from message table instead of fetching all messages after 2 second again and again..  Below is my code.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//get new message every 2 second
 var interval = setTimeout(function () {

$("#chatting").load("get_message_ajax.php", {c_id:c_id, from_id:from_id, to_id:to_id});


}, 2000);

});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['c_id'])){

$conversation_id = isset($_POST["c_id"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["c_id"])) : "";
$from_id = isset($_POST["from_id"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["from_id"])) : "";
$to_id = isset($_POST["to_id"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["to_id"])) : "";


//fetch all the messages of $user_id(loggedin user) and $user_two from their conversation

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` m WHERE conversation_id=:conversation_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":conversation_id"=>$conversation_id));
$m = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Please help me out.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple and quick solution**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var chatData = ""; // default set emty

//get new message every 2 second
 var interval = setTimeout(function () {

    $.post( "get_message_ajax.php", {c_id:c_id, from_id:from_id, to_id:to_id})
        .done(function( data ) {
            if(chatData !== data){ // if changes are exist in result then update
                $("#chatting").html(data);
            }
            chatData = data;
        }
    });

}, 2000);

});
```

Comment: it hit database every 2 sec. not when new row insert in db

Comment: this would be help here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100594/refresh-content-automatically-if-the-database-changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100594/refresh-content-automatically-if-the-database-changes)