# How can I automatically refresh my site while editing the CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, emacs

I am working on HTML/CSS/JavaScript from within emacs. My workflow is currently

```
Make a change -> Alt-Tab to browser -> F5 (refresh) -> Alt Tab to emacs
```

Do any extensions exist that would auto-refresh the browser on a change? Or, possibly a better idea, when I hit a key combination from within emacs?

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309599/automatically-refresh-browser-in-response-to-file-system-changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1, refresh the browser on interval:**

With the addition of a single meta tag into your html document, you can instruct the browser to automatically refresh at a designated interval number of seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
```

**Option 2, firefox plugin to refresh on document change:**

A Firefox Add-on, called [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/), will monitor your project folder, and, every time it detects a change to the source files, it’ll reload Firefox.

**Option 3, refresh the page from Emacs, vim or shell script:**

There is a [firefox plugin called IMACROS](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/) that let you define a script that will remote control firefox from a file on disk.  You can create a remote control script, and then program Emacs, vim or shell script to tell firefox to run the remote control script when you are ready, thus refreshing the page.  You would need to create a keyboard hook to kickoff the script on save.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried [impatient-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode) and it worked nicely for what I needed. It also can be extended to do things like, for example, display the contents of a buffer you are editing in an iframe alongside other buffers etc.

Comment: You can check out the http://youtu.be/QV6XVyXjBO8 video of [impatient-mode in action](http://youtu.be/QV6XVyXjBO8).

Answer (score 3):

I use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which help you scaffold web apps, which uses Grunt and the command

```
$grunt server
```

It is a simple setup that enables "livereload". I then set up my localhost or rather IP:9000 which enables live reload of any device in my local network upon file save of all watched files (scss, js, coffee, html) etc.  So you can see the site change upon save not only on your desktop, but your tablet, mobile devices, cross browser, smart tv etc..

It also runs compass, unit tests, uglifies & concatenates, does the dishes, walks the dog you name it. Then "$ grunt build" creates complete distributions to deploy.

It's worth a look, it's a bit of a setup, I had a few hurdles, but it's amazing what you get back.